# Get Word Count of a Column using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, word-count

I have a table with a column called `Description`. The column is populated with text data. I want to create a query that returns the amount of words in each description.

My thought was to create a function that takes in a value, and returns the amount of words found in the inputted text.

```
SELECT dbo.GetWordCount(Description) FROM TABLE
```

For example, if the description is "Hello World! Have a nice day.", the query should return 6.

How can I get the word count of the description column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this proposed solution: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/functions/count-words.aspx

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[WordCount] ( @InputString VARCHAR(4000) ) 
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Index          INT
DECLARE @Char           CHAR(1)
DECLARE @PrevChar       CHAR(1)
DECLARE @WordCount      INT

SET @Index = 1
SET @WordCount = 0

WHILE @Index <= LEN(@InputString)
BEGIN
    SET @Char     = SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index, 1)
    SET @PrevChar = CASE WHEN @Index = 1 THEN ' '
                         ELSE SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index - 1, 1)
                    END

    IF @PrevChar = ' ' AND @Char != ' '
        SET @WordCount = @WordCount + 1

    SET @Index = @Index + 1
END

RETURN @WordCount

END
GO
```

Usage Example:

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(4000)
SET @String = 'Health Insurance is an insurance against expenses incurred through illness of the insured.'

SELECT [dbo].[WordCount] ( @String )
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a little cumbersome but it handles the whitespace issue nicely, its fast and inline, no udf.

```
DECLARE @Term VARCHAR(100) = '  this   is   pretty fast '

SELECT @Term, LEN(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(' '+@Term,'  ',' '+CHAR(1)) ,CHAR(1)+' ',''),CHAR(1),'')) -  LEN(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(' '+@Term,'  ',' '+CHAR(1)) ,CHAR(1)+' ',''),CHAR(1),''),' ','')) [Word Count]
```

Comment: The second LEN doesn't need the special handling of multiple spaces, because spaces get eliminated in the last REPLACE anyway. This should be enough: ``LEN(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(' '+@Term,'  ',' '+CHAR(1)) ,CHAR(1)+' ',''),CHAR(1),'')) - LEN(REPLACE(@Term,' ',''))``

Answer (score 2):

Generalized Syntax:

```
SELECT (LENGTH(column_name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(column_name, ' ', ''))),column_name1,column_name2 FROM table_name;
```

In case, if you want to calculate how many words are there in single 'address' column of a table named 'employeeDetails' then:

```
SELECT (LENGTH(address) - LENGTH(REPLACE(address, ' ', ''))),address,employee_name FROM employeeDetails ;
```

Comment: You need to add +1 because there is one less space than there are words.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Mortalus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/605129/mortalus)'s answer I'd use an **inline function** rather than scalar (*Note - this function will work from SQL Server 2012 and up)
***for Previous versions of SQL Server see below:***

```
    /*SQL Server 2012 and up*/
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_WordCount 
    (

    @str VARCHAR(8000) 

    )
    RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN

    WITH Tally (n) AS
    (
        SELECT TOP (LEN(@str)) ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
        FROM (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(n)
        CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) b(n)
        CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) c(n)
        CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) d(n)
    )
    , BreakChar as
    (
        SELECT  SUBSTRING(@str , n , 1) [Char] , N
        FROM Tally

    )
    , Analize as 
    (
        SELECT * , lag([Char],1) OVER (ORDER BY N) PrevChar
        FROM BreakChar
    )

        SELECT WordCount = COUNT(1) + 1 
        FROM Analize
        WHERE [Char] != PrevChar
        AND PrevChar = ' '
```

How to Use:

```
    DECLARE @str varchar(1000) = 'It''s now or never I ain''t gonna live forever'
    SELECT * FROM dbo.udf_WordCount(@str) --> 9
```

**SQL Server 2008 and lower:

```
    /*SQL Server 2008 and down*/
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_WordCount_2008 
    (
    --declare
    @str VARCHAR(8000) 
    --= 'It''s now or never I ain''t gonna live forever'
    )
    RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN

    WITH Tally (n) AS
    (
        SELECT TOP (LEN(@str)) ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
        FROM (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(n)
        CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) b(n)
        CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) c(n)
        CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) d(n)
    )
    , BreakChar as
    (
        SELECT  SUBSTRING(@str , n , 1) [Char] , N
        FROM Tally

    )
    , Analize as 
    (
        SELECT a.* , b.Char PrevChar
        FROM BreakChar a
        JOIN BreakChar b
        on a.n = b.n+1


    )

        SELECT WordCount = COUNT(1) + 1 
        FROM Analize
        WHERE [Char] != PrevChar
        AND PrevChar = ' '
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the same code used in [Mortalus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15353017/4660897), which I originally found [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=129034).

This solution is a more efficient and more concise version of that code. I've also add some explanation for the code that will hopefully make this answer clearer for future readers.

---

The following [user defined function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/user-defined-functions) takes in a string of text, and then loops through the each character of the inputted text. If the previous character was a space, the word count is increased by one.

Since the word count is calculated by counting the spaces between the words, there will always be 1 less space than actual words. To counteract this, start `@PrevChar` with the value of `' '`. Then, when the loop is run for the first time, when the code then reaches `IF @PrevChar = ' '`, it will return true, and the word count will be increase by one. This works even if the text has a length of 0, since in that case, it just won't get passed the `@Index <= LEN(@InputString)` check, and the word count will never be increased. (This replaces the `CASE` statement used in the linked answer.)

`AND @CurrentChar != ' '` is used to solve the problem of double spacing being counted as multiple words. If the previous character is a space, but the current character is also a space, move on to the next index without increasing the word count. The next iteration will then only have `@PrevChar` set to `' '`, and so the word count will only be increase once for the double space.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[WordCount] (@InputString VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Index INT = 1
    DECLARE @CurrentChar CHAR(1)

    --Initialize the previous character as a space.
    DECLARE @PrevChar CHAR(1) = ' '

    DECLARE @WordCount INT = 0

    WHILE @Index <= LEN(@InputString)
    BEGIN
        --Set the current character to equal the character in the index 
        --position of the inputted text.
        SET @CurrentChar= SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index, 1)

        --If the previous character was a space and the current character
        --is not a space, increase the wordcount by 1.
        IF @PrevChar = ' ' AND @CurrentChar != ' '
            SET @WordCount = @WordCount + 1

        --Increase the index counter by 1.
        SET @Index = @Index + 1

        --Now that we are done with the current character, set the previous
        --character to equal the current character.
        SET @PrevChar = @CurrentChar
    END

    RETURN @WordCount
END
```

Answer (score 0):

requisites: SQL Server 2016 and later

I use this in my sp , I receive a sentence, so i can handle inner spaces.

[image]

```
SELECT value from STRING_SPLIT(@oracion1,' ')
```

now I filter for values with text and count them for to achieve this :

[image]

```
SELECT count(value) from STRING_SPLIT(@str,' ') where len(value)>0
```

@oracion1 colud be  N"JUAN ES      CARPINTERO             " or @oracion1 could be  N"JUAN ES CARPINTERO  "